# How is an external monitor recognised?

Tags: multiple-monitors, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro, external-display

On Mountain Lion 10.8.2 (and also on Snow Leopard as far as I know) external monitors are somehow recognised and remembered by my laptop.
For example: When I change the wallpaper on the external monitor at work, it does not change on the external monitor at home. The same holds for the placement of the secondary display w.r.t. the laptop.

Where is this information stored? Is there some kind of system file responsible for this?